# No Column Name on executing stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on this stored proc which is suppose to give values based on the input Quarter and year.

The stored proc has dynamic 2 columns which has the Sum of Amounts. But in place of the column name its showing No column name for those 2 columns (S1, P1) and even not giving the values.

```
create proc [dbo].[Summary]
@Quarter int,
@Year int
AS
BEGIN

Declare @SC AS decimal(18,0)
Declare @PO AS decimal(18,0)
Declare @INV AS decimal(18,0)

SELECT BD.id, 
       BD.project, 
       status, 
       (SELECT Sum(amount) AS S1 
        FROM   details a 
        WHERE  status = 'S1' 
               AND BD.project = a.project), 
       (SELECT Sum(amount) AS P1 
        FROM   details b 
        WHERE  status = 'P1' 
               AND BD.project = b.project) 
FROM   projectdetails (nolock) BD 
       INNER JOIN details (nolock) D 
               ON BD.project = D.project 
WHERE  BD.quarter = @Quarter 
       AND BD.year = @Year 
       AND BD.project = D.project 
GROUP  BY BD.lineid, 
          BD.project, 
          status 
END
```

Comment: Use alias name to those two sub-queries to get column names in result. *even not giving the values.*  You have to figure out that by checking input parameter values with table data

Comment: those values are suppose to be the sum(Amount)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a function in a column list, the original column name is not retained. You need to use a column alias. For example:

```
SELECT BD.ID,
        BD.Project,
        Status,
        (SELECT Sum(amount) AS S1 
         FROM   details a 
         WHERE  status = 'S1' 
                AND BD.project = a.project) AS SumS1, --Added alias here
        (SELECT Sum(amount) AS P1 
         FROM   details b 
         WHERE  status = 'P1' 
                AND BD.project = b.project) AS SumP1 --And here
FROM ...
```

As to why you are not getting data, that is because your query is not returning any data. Try running those select statements separately to see where the problem is.

Comment: Yeah I had to alias. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem! You can click the check box to accept the answer so future users can see the answer that solved your problem too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give them alias outside the Subquery

```
create proc [dbo].[Summary]
@Quarter int,
@Year int
AS
BEGIN

Declare @SC AS decimal(18,0)
Declare @PO AS decimal(18,0)
Declare @INV AS decimal(18,0)

SELECT BD.ID, 
BD.Project,
Status,
(Select SUM(Amount) from Details a where Status='S1' and BD.Project = a.Project) as S1, 
(Select SUM(Amount) from Details b where Status='P1' and BD.Project = b.Project) as P1
 FROM ProjectDetails (NOLOCK) BD
 inner join Details (NOLOCK) D on BD.Project = D.Project

 WHERE BD.Quarter = @Quarter and BD.Year = @Year and BD.Project = D.Project
 Group By BD.LineID, BD.Project,Status
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `alias` name to those two sub-queries to get column names in result. It can be rewritten like this

```
SELECT BD.id, 
       BD.project, 
       status, 
       Sum(case when status = 'S1' then amount else 0 end) AS S1,
       Sum(case when status = 'P1' then amount else 0 end) AS P1 
FROM   projectdetails BD 
       INNER JOIN details  D 
               ON BD.project = D.project 
WHERE  BD.quarter = @Quarter 
       AND BD.year = @Year 
       AND BD.project = D.project 
GROUP  BY BD.lineid, 
          BD.project, 
          status
```